# How do I populate 3 spinners in a fragment and get selected item in text view?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

**The 2nd spinner is based on the 1st spinner and the 3rd spinner based on the 2nd spinner.**

Here I tried but it seems whenever I select the second item, it resets and the 1st item is selected.

I am unable to select other options only the first one is selected through out the output.

This code is not working, it seems something is going wrong:

```
public class UnsolvedQuestionPaper extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Nullable
    Spinner s1, s2, s3;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unsolved_question_paper, container, false);
        s1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Branch);
        s2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Sem);
        s3 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Subject);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        return view;


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Question Paper");
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
        String sp2 = String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
        String sp3 = String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());
       /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sp2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), sp3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        */
        if (sp1.equals("F.E") && !sp2.contains("SEM 1,SEM 2")) {

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("SEM 1");
            list.add("SEM 2");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
        }
        if (sp1.contentequals("I.T,C.E,EXTC,MECH,CIVIL") && !sp2.contains("SEM 3,SEM 4,SEM 5,SEM 6,SEM 7,SEM 8")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("SEM 3");
            list.add("SEM 4");
            list.add("SEM 5");
            list.add("SEM 6");
            list.add("SEM 7");
            list.add("SEM 8");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);


        }

        if (sp1.contentEquals("F.E")) {
            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 1")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied Chemistry 1");
                list1.add("Applied Mathematics 1");
                list1.add("Applied Physics 1");
                list1.add("Basic Electrical & Electronics Engineering");
                list1.add("Engineering Mechanics");
                list1.add("Environmental Studies");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 2")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied Chemistry 2");
                list1.add("Applied Mathematics 2");
                list1.add("Applied Physics 2");
                list1.add("Communication Skills");
                list1.add("Engineering Drawing");
                list1.add("Structured Programming Approach");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
            }
        } else if (sp1.contentEquals("I.T")) {
            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 3")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 3");
                list1.add("Data structure and algorithm analysis");
                list1.add("Object oriented programming methodology");
                list1.add("Anlog and digital circuits");
                list1.add("Database management systems");
                list1.add("Principales of anlog and digital communication");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 4")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 4");
                list1.add("Computer network");
                list1.add("Computer organization and architecture");
                list1.add("Automata theory");
                list1.add("Web programming");
                list1.add("Information theory and coding");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 5")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Computer graphics and virtual reality");
                list1.add("Operating system");
                list1.add("Microcontroller and embedded systems");
                list1.add("Advanced database management systems");
                list1.add("Open source technologies");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter7 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter7.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter7);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 6")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

                list1.add("Software engineering");
                list1.add("Distributed systems");
                list1.add("System and web security");
                list1.add("Data mining and business intelligence");
                list1.add("Advance internet Technology");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter8 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter8.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter8.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter8);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 7")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Wireless technology");
                list1.add("Cloud computing");
                list1.add("Software project management");
                list1.add("Intelligent system");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter9 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter9.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter9.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter9);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 8")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Big data analytics");
                list1.add("Storage network management  and retrieval");
                list1.add("Computer simulation and modeling");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter10 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter10.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter10.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter10);
            }
        } else if (sp1.contentEquals("C.E")) {

            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 3")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 3");
                list1.add("Object oriented programming methodology");
                list1.add("Data structures");
                list1.add("Digital logic design and analysis");
                list1.add("Discrete structures");
                list1.add("Electronics circuits and communication fundamentals");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter11 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter11.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter11.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter11);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 4")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 4");
                list1.add("Analysis of algorithms");
                list1.add("Computer organization and architecture");
                list1.add("Data base management systems");
                list1.add("Theoretical computer science");
                list1.add("Computer graphics");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter12 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter12.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter12.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter12);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 5")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Microprocessor");
                list1.add("Operating systems");
                list1.add("Structured and object oriented analysis and design");
                list1.add("Computer network");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter13 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter13.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter13.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter13);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 6")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("System programming and compiler construction");
                list1.add("Software engineering");
                list1.add("Distributed database");
                list1.add("Mobile communication and computing");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter14 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter14.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter14.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter14);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 7")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Digital singal and image processing");
                list1.add("Robotics and AI");
                list1.add("Mobile computing");
                list1.add("System security");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter15 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter15.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter15.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter15);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 8")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Distributed computing");
                list1.add("Multimedia system design");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter16 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter16.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter16.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter16);
            }
        } else if (sp1.contentEquals("EXTC")) {
            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 3")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 3");
                list1.add("Analog electronics 1");
                list1.add("Digital electronics");
                list1.add(" Circuits and transmission lines");
                list1.add("Electronic instrument and measurements");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter17 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter17.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter17.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter17);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 4")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied maths 4");
                list1.add("Analog electronics 2");
                list1.add("  Microprocessors and peripherals");
                list1.add("  Wave theory and propagation");
                list1.add("Signals and systems");
                list1.add(" Control system");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter18 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter18.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter18.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter18);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 5")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("  Microcontroller and applisubions");
                list1.add("  Anlog communication");
                list1.add("  Random signal analysis");
                list1.add("  RF modeling and antennas");
                list1.add("  Integrated circuits");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter19 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter19.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter19.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter19);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 6")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("  Digital communication");
                list1.add("  Discrete time signal processing");
                list1.add("  Computer communication and telecom networks");
                list1.add("  Television engineering");
                list1.add("  Operating systems");
                list1.add("  VLSI design");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter20 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter20.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter20.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter20);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 7")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("  Mobile communication system");
                list1.add("  Fundamentals of microwave engineering");
                list1.add("  Computer communication network");
                list1.add("  Discrete time signal processing");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter21 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter21.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter21.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter21);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 8")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Advance microwave engineering");
                list1.add(" Optical fiber communication");
                list1.add(" Wireless network");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter22 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter22.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter22.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter22);
            }
        } else if (sp1.contentEquals("MECH")) {
            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 3")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Applied maths 3");
                list1.add(" Production process 1");
                list1.add(" Thermodynamics");
                list1.add(" Strength of material");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter23 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter23.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter23.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter23);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 4")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("  Applied maths 4");
                list1.add("  Production process 2");
                list1.add(" Fluid mechanics");
                list1.add(" Theory of machine 1");
                list1.add(" Material technology");
                list1.add(" Industrial electronics");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter24 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter24.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter24.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter24);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 5")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("  Production process 3");
                list1.add(" I C engines");
                list1.add(" Mechanical instrument and control");
                list1.add(" Theory of machine 2");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter25 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter25.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter25.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter25);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 6")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Metrology and quality engineering");
                list1.add("Machine design 1");
                list1.add(" Mechanical vibrations");
                list1.add(" Thermal and fluid power engineering");
                list1.add("     Mechaltronics");
                list1.add(" Finite element alaysis");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter26 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter26.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter26.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter26);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 7")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Machine design 2");
                list1.add(" CAD/CAM/CIM");
                list1.add(" Mechanical utility system");
                list1.add(" Production planning and control");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter27 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter27.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter27.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter27);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 8")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Design of mechanical system");
                list1.add(" Industrial engineering and management");
                list1.add(" Refrigerator and air conditioning");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter28 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter28.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter28.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter28);
            }
        } else if (sp1.contentEquals("CIVIL")) {
            if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 3")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Applied mathematics 3");
                list1.add(" Surveying 1");
                list1.add(" Strength of materials");
                list1.add(" Building materials and construction");
                list1.add(" Engineering geology");
                list1.add(" Fluid mechanics 1");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter29 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter29.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter29.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter29);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 4")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Applied mathematics 4");
                list1.add(" Surveying 2");
                list1.add(" Structural analysis 1");
                list1.add(" Building design and drawing 1");
                list1.add(" Concrete technology");
                list1.add(" Fluid mechanics 2");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter30 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter30.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter30.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter30);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 5")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Structural analysis 2");
                list1.add(" Geotechnical engineering 1");
                list1.add(" Building design and drawing 2");
                list1.add("Applied hydraulics 1");
                list1.add("Transportation engineering 1");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter31 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter31.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter31.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter31);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 6")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Geotechnical engineering 2");
                list1.add(" Design and drawing of steel structures");
                list1.add("Applied hydraulics 2");
                list1.add(" Transportation engineering 2");
                list1.add(" Environmental engineering 1");
                list1.add("Theory of reinforced prestressed concrete");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter32 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter32.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter32.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter32);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 7")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add(" Limit state method for reinforced concrete structures");
                list1.add("Quantity survey, estimation and valuation");
                list1.add(" Irrigation engineering");
                list1.add(" Environmental engineering 2");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter33 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter33.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter33.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter33);
            } else if (sp2.contentEquals("SEM 8")) {

                List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                list1.add("Design and drawing for reinforced concrete structures");
                list1.add("Construction engineering");
                list1.add("Construction management");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter34 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                dataAdapter34.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter34.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter34);

            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```